# I thought it wise

Tags: expressions

> I thought it wise to let you know in advance.

Is 'I thought it wise' an expression? Should it be 'I thought it is wise to let you know in advance.'?

Comment: No, it's idiomatic. think something wise/intelligent/interesting, etc.

Comment: Yes, it's a similar construction to "I find it odd..."

Comment: The term **expression** is too broad and polysemous to be of any value. Consider an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

"I thought it wise" is a commonly used phrase. "I thought it is wise" is hardly ever used.

[This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+thought+it+wise%2CI+thought+it+is+wise&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) Shows that the google corpus finds too few examples of "I thought it is wise" to report.

In general a construction such as:

> I {verb} it {adjective/adverb}.

will often be valid English particularly when the verb is "think" or "find" or "feel", as the comment by gotube suggests.

> - I thought it helpful to A.
> - I found it distasteful.
> - I found it funny.
>   I felt it polite to B.

All the above are valid and natural.

Comment: "I thought it is wise..." would in any event be rather clumsy. The alternative to "I thought it wise..." would be "I thought it **to be** wise", which is in fact what it is saying but with the "to be" elided.

Comment: @WS2 Yes when the main verb "think" is in the past tense, the use of "is" is awkward. But "I think it is wise" is not awkward inn the same way.

Comment: Quite so - and "I thought it was wise" equally so.  "I thought it is wise" is more than clumsy - it is ungrammatical.

Comment: About the grammar: it's an extraposition construction where "it" is a dummy pronoun functioning as object and the subordinate clause as extraposed object

Comment: @BillJ Aren't such concepts a bit much for English learners?